# Problems using custom generator in keras reading 3D numpy files

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am reading in 3D numpy files stored in a directory where the file name contains the label but I keep getting "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class '**main**.my_custom_generator'>, <class 'NoneType'>". When commencing training with model.fit.

'''

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import math

class my_custom_generator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) *
        self.batch_size]

        return (np.array([np.expand_dims(np.rollaxis(np.load(file_name),2),axis=-1) for file_name in batch_x]), 
                np.expand_dims(np.array([int(file_name.split(':')[-1].split('.')[0])/180 for file_name in batch_x]),axis =-1))

batch_size = 2
my_training_batch_generator = my_custom_generator(x_train,x_train,batch_size)
my_valid_batch_generator = my_custom_generator(x_valid,x_valid,batch_size)

for xx, yy in my_training_batch_generator: 
    print(type(xx))
    print(xx.shape)
    print(type(yy))
    print(yy.shape)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2, 450, 8, 3, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2, 450, 8, 3, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(2, 1)

from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPool3D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout, Input, BatchNormalization
from keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from keras.models import Model
## input layer
input_layer = Input((450, 8, 3,1))
## convolutional layers
conv_layer1 = Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(10, 3, 3), 
                     dilation_rate=(10, 1, 1), activation='relu')(input_layer)
conv_layer1 = BatchNormalization()(conv_layer1)

conv_layer2 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(20, 3, 1), 
                     dilation_rate=(5, 1, 1), activation='relu')(conv_layer1)
pooling_layer1 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 3, 1))(conv_layer2)
pooling_layer1 = BatchNormalization()(pooling_layer1)

conv_layer3 = Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(20, 1, 1), 
                     dilation_rate=(5, 1, 1), activation='relu')(pooling_layer1)
pooling_layer2 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(10, 1, 1))(conv_layer3)
pooling_layer2 = BatchNormalization()(pooling_layer2)

flatten_layer = Flatten()(pooling_layer2)
dense_layer1 = Dense(units=48, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dense_layer1 = BatchNormalization()(dense_layer1)
output_layer = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer1)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.summary()
model_train = model.fit(my_training_batch_generator,epochs=50,
                                  batch_size=batch_size)
```

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class '**main**.my_custom_generator'>, <class 'NoneType'>

The x_train and x_valid are lists of file locations for the numpy files.

The shape of the arrays and dtype appear to be correct from the generator. Any thoughts? Please and thank you.

'''

Comment: You are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras and this is not supported.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!